# What is the correct way to write this javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand javascript and javascript functions. This function is used to change the look of a button.

```
function changeButton(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = btn.style.backgroundColor == "black" ? "white" : "black";
    btn.style.color = btn.style.color == "white" ? "black" : "white";
    btn.innerHTML = btn.innerHTML == 'GOOD JOB' ? 'CLICK ME' : 'GOOD JOB';
}
```

It works just fine. But when I look at this function I see a lot of repetition. The basic structure seems to be `element = element == value1 ? value2 : value1`

So in my mind this should work:

```
function toggleValue(elem, val1, val2){
    elem = elem == val1 ? val2 : val1
}

function changeButton(){
    var x = btn.style.backgroundColor
    var y = btn.style.color
    var z = btn.innerHTML
    toggleValue(x, 'white', 'black')
    toggleValue(y, 'black', 'white')
    toggleValue(z, 'CLICK ME', 'GOOD JOB')
}
```

But it does not work and I don't understand why. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work? And is there a way to make it work?

Comment: A better way would be to use CSS and `classList.toggle` to turn the "active" class on and off.

Comment: `x.y = ...` modifies the property of an object. `x = ...` reassigns a local variable.

Comment: `var x = btn.style.backgroundColor`, in this you are just copying a `value` which is there in the `backgroundColor` property. This will not act as a `reference`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work, because you hand over a primitive value an not a reference to the property.

```
function toggleValue(elem, prop, val1, val2){
    elem[prop] = elem[prop] == val1 ? val2 : val1
}

function changeButton(){
    toggleValue(btn.style, 'backgroundColor', 'white', 'black')
    toggleValue(btn.style, 'color', 'black', 'white')
    toggleValue(btn, 'innerHTML', 'CLICK ME', 'GOOD JOB')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are passing the **String which is immutable**.

You can create one more argument - **property**.

```
function toggleValue(elem, prop, val1, val2){
    elem[prop] = elem[prop] == val1 ? val2 : val1
}

function changeButton(){
    var x = btn.style;
    var y = btn.style;
    var z = btn;
    toggleValue(x, "backgroundColor", 'white', 'black');
    toggleValue(y, "color", 'black', 'white');
    toggleValue(z, "innerHTML", 'CLICK ME', 'GOOD JOB');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggleValue(elem, val1, val2, ButtonStyleType) {        
        elem = elem == val1 ? val2 : val1;
        if (ButtonStyleType == 'backgroundColor')
            btn.style.backgroundColor = elem;
        else if (ButtonStyleType == 'color')
            btn.style.color = elem;
        else if (ButtonStyleType == 'innerHtml')
            btn.innerHTML = elem;
    }
    function changeButton() {        
        var x = btn.style.backgroundColor;
        var y = btn.style.color;
        var z = btn.innerHTML;
        toggleValue(x, 'green', 'yellow', 'backgroundColor');
        toggleValue(y, 'black', 'Orange', 'color');
        toggleValue(z, 'Default', 'GOOD JOB', 'innerHtml');
    }
```

```html
<button id="btn" style="background-color:green; color:black;">Default</button><br />
        <br />
        <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="changeButton();">Click here to update button style</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between pass by value and pass by reference
[to know more about that click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)